# how to show limited text in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text like this in HTML:

```
 <p>text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</p>
```

Is it possible to make it like this:

```
text texttext texttext texttext text.....
```

Comment: what do you want to use for it.. php? javascript?

Comment: use CSS3 Vertical ellipsis; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css

Comment: Do you want to strip the <p>-tag or cut the text-overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncating long strings with CSS: feasible yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below CSS style for `<p>` tag.

```
p{
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/mgfno5va/)

Comment: The OP requires a JS solution (see comments)

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/otf9h9pn

HTML:

```
<p class="ellipsis">text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext</p>
```

CSS:

```
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20em;
}
```

Comment: The OP requires a JS solution (see comments)

Answer (score 0):

yeah that's possible with `ellipsis`

```
dl dt {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The OP requires a JS solution (see comments)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for my projects. You need JQuery.

How it works: assign the class `.more` to the `div` containing your text.

Check my [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emvNpr)

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Show more >";
var lesstext = "Show less";


$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <html>
     <head>
    <title>jQuery Read More/Less Toggle Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    .morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

For a single line of text use `text-overflow:ellipsis;`, like so

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

(Source [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/))

For multi-line text it gets trickier. Check out this link http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/

Personally for multi-line text I used a jQuery plugin, called [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do in pure JavaScript with `substring()`

```js
var str = document.getElementById("longlist").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("shorten").innerHTML = str.substring(0,36)+".....";
```

```html
<strong>Actual text</strong>
<p id="longlist">text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</p>
<hr />
<strong>Result:</strong>
<p id="shorten"></p>
```