# Overflow element when using percentage widths

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to do a one line overflow on an element in a `td` when it's contents exceed that of its parents when using relative widths.

```
 ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 |10%    60%                                       30%                 |
 |Left   Middle (This content should not exceed... Right               |
 |                                                                     |
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JE9EU/6/) is what I've managed so far. A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426398/css-javascript-to-force-html-table-row-on-a-single-line) received [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426405/768510) that I thought would be a solution, however that doesn't appear to work with % widths. I am looking for a CSS solution before resorting to a JavaScript work around.

*Note: I don't need an inner element, if CSS styling can be applied directly to the outer element that would be great also.*

Many thank,

Thomas Nadin

Comment: Which browsers are you targeting?

Comment: WebKit, with development been performed on Google Chrome 17.0.963.56 m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to simply change

```
 table {
     width: 100%;
 }
```

to

```
 table {
     width: 100%;
     table-layout:fixed;
 }
```

and everything will work as you expect it to work. (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/JE9EU/7/))

All the magic lies in the `table-layout:fixed;` property, which defines that the table should be *exactly* as wide as you have defined it.

`table-layout:fixed;` is pretty well supported, except for IE/Mac (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/table-layout).

**EDIT**

I just read the question again, and saw that you want to drop the inner `<div>`. With this solution it's possible, just drop it and apply the class `overflow` to the `td.second` (so you are flexible and can apply it also to multiple columns if you want to). [See the result in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/JE9EU/8/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few notes:

"third" is misspelled in the HTML.

```
<td class="thrid">Right</td>
```

And I realize it's for test purposes but `overflow` should be `.overflow`.

```
.second overflow {
    width: 50px;
}
```

When I remove `white-space: nowrap;`, it works perfectly in WebKit. What browser are you testing?

```
.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Without `white-space: nowrap;` my text, as expected, wraps on to multiple lines. I only want the text to be on one line and overflow at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/qWS46/

Comment: Thank *you for* noticing my grammatical fumbles, question's jsfiddle has been updated. I can't believe I got them the wrong way around, I'm really not all with it today.