# css: table-row: Way to force one table row to take full height of table and push second row out of visible area

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables, tablerow

This is a similar post: [force table row into single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426398/css-javascript-to-force-html-table-row-on-a-single-line) but instead of forcing the content to disappear I'm trying to force the actual row to disappear. I'm using css display: tables to get content vertically centered in the div

So I have a site with the general set-up of this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Row1                                           |
-------------------------------------------------
|Row2                                           |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have the html set up as:

```
<div class="A"> //display: table

  <div class="B"> //display: table-row, height: 100% // ROW 1
    <div class="C"> display: table-cell vertically centered contents go here
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="B"> //display: table-row // ROW 2
    <div class="C"> display: table-cell vertically centered contents go here
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

By setting the height of my "b" div's to 100% I'm trying to force them to take up the full height of the table (so that only one will be visible at a time – then I'm pushing them up or down with javascript).

The problem is that the table is growing to show both table rows, Row 2 is always visible. I don't want to use display: none.

Also, the table height is variable so I can't set the table to i.e. 200px and the table row to 200px.

You can see a version of what the javascript will do here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pappley/BGy6R/12/).  Note, the fiddle is a fixed height so I achieved the vertical centering with margins. In the example above, I need the height to be variable so I have to use another method to vertically center the content in the divs (thus my choice of display: table)

Answer (score 0):

```
display:none;
```

is the way to go, 
but I suppose you can also use

```
 height: 0px;
```

Comment: height: 0 won't work because it doesn't account for the contents of the table cell. Essentially, height: 0 is ignored. And I can't use display: none because of the javascript I'm using. A display: none doesn't allow for the animation/transition I need.