# how to find point in line and then after add a content in new line

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

now my content is a one line but I want to new content is new line after the point(.)

[image]

.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Career()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:0000/Home/DisplayVacancyData").Result;

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //data = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync();
                //List<Vacancy> products = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Vacancy>>();
                string result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                List<Vacancy> vaca = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vacancy>>(result);
                ViewBag.message = vaca + "<br />";
                return View("Career",vaca);
                 
            }
            return View();
        }
```

.cshtml

```
<table class="table table-striped border">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Vacancy Title</th>
            <th>Vacancy Position</th>
            <th>Vacancy Experience</th>
            <th>Vacancy Jobdescription</th>
            <th>Vacancy RequiredSkil</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var carr in Model)
        {
            //string newline = "\n";

            <tr>
                <td>@carr.vacancytitle</td>
                <td>@carr.vacancyposition</td>
                <td>@carr.vacancyexperience</td>

                @*if()*@

                <td>@carr.vacancyjobdescription@*<text> & nbsp;</ text >*@</td>
                <td>@carr.vacancyrequiredskill</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Apply for Job", "ApplyForJob")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

means after point new content in separate line

logic is first find the point(.) in line then after add a new line

```
string newline = "\n";
if(carr.vacancyjobdescription)
{   
   //issue is here how to find out point in line
   and then add a <text>newline</text>
   
}
```

what I am trying - **main issue is how to find the point**

```
               <td>
                    @if (carr.vacancyjobdescription != null)
                    {
                        @carr.vacancyjobdescription
                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                    }
                </td>
```

Comment: Manipulate your vacancyrequiredskill property value by replacing your point with </br> in Controller action method and then use with @Html.Raw() function in View

Comment: @MayurAsodariya I have not static content data is coming from database ```ViewBag.message = vaca + "<br />";```   vaca is not static content see I add a controller code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <td>

        @{
            string skillHtml = @carr.vacancyrequiredskill;
            skillHtml = skillHtml.Replace(".", "</br>");
        }
        @*Here we gonna display the html*@
        @Html.Raw(skillHtml)
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{string data = "Hello. This is Test. Yo";
data= data.Replace(".", "</br>");}


@*Then to display your value  use...*@
@Html.Raw(data)
```

Comment: issue is solved I want to display content in straight line(means first line content display in straight line) which place I am doing wrong my whole content in table https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPBvf.png

Comment: You can provide two separate answers if the proposed solutions are unrelated. However, for solutions that are related provide them in the same answer and rather edit your original answer.

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring I'll take care for that no onwards.

Comment: @AayushiBabariya Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426398/css-javascript-to-force-html-table-row-on-a-single-line